# Site loading blank white page, console shows 'unexpected token' error

Tags: heroku

I have this site, it runs just fine on my local, but when I deploy it to Heroku, I just see a blank page:

https://peachproperties.herokuapp.com

The Heroku deployment goes through just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you running? Did you check that heroku has everything it needs to deploy the site. (Any dependencies?)

Comment: I'm using web pack. How do I deploy that to heroku?

Comment: on my local, in addition to running rails server, I also run this to get the app to work: `webpack --progress --colors --watch`

Comment: Ok when you deploy on heroku, did you mention to install all that? Did you do any configuration?

Comment: Like adding `webpack` to the `devdependencies`, and adding your command to the `script` part?

Comment: uh, no. sorry i'm a newbie to coding, and haven't deployed anything more than a simple rails app to heroku before..not sure how to do the things you're saying?